# Как правильно отправить данные с Json?

Tags: java, android, json

Приложение каждый раз когда обращается к серверу прикрепляет к запросу `Json` файл в который складывается все данные

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("1", 1);
        data.put("2", 2);
        data.put("3", 3);
```

Но теперь нужно с этим файлом отправить 30 мб данных...

Не пойму как правильно сделать? Я так понимаю, что я не могу положить в `Json` 30 мб байтов...

Как правильно передать такой запрос?

Comment: А откуда инфа о том, что это не получится стандартным способом? Какие-то ограничения JSON?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну мне кажется это не правильно пихать в json 30 mb ... Я вот тут нашел MultipartEntity.... Но я так понял вроде это deprecated... Что скажите?

Comment: Ну, это наверное что-то из HttpUrlConnection или как там он называется... Лично я OkHttp использую и бед не знаю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я все хочу посмотреть как работать в Retrofit и OkHttp... Но к этому моменту я вроде понял как решить свою проблему... Сейчас доделаю и если ок то опубликую

Comment: Вам нужно отправильно JSON строку размером в 30 мегабайт или JSON строку + какой то файл размером 30  Mb. Если второй вариант то можете сделать PUT запрос на сервер:   json передать заголовком запроса а файл в теле запроса.

Comment: @KirillStoianov да так и собираюсь сделать)

Comment: В json можно загнать байты, есни использовать, например, base64 encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В итоге нужно было прикрепить к заголовку самого `HTTPUrlConnection`...

То есть поток для записи открываем так же просто в заголовок вкладываем все что нам нужно как сопутствующие файлы

```
 @Override
public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url, String newValue, Context context) {

    JSONObject service = getJsonObject(context);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("authorization", UtilClass.getAuthToken(context));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("service", service.toString());
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", newValue);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.connect();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return urlConnection;
}
```

Comment: Так если удовлетворительный ответ найден, может быть, стоит конкурс отменить, чтобы вопрос больше не высвечивался на главной странице?

Comment: @m.vokhm Там же когда создаешь конкурс то указываешь доп комментарий в котором я указал, что может у кого то есть другой подход... Я просто с конекшенами работал совсем не много и может кто то хочет изложить свое видение)

Comment: OK. Я не понял. Я не спец, но может, как-то разбивать этот JSON на части, и по частям пересылать?

Comment: @m.vokhm Может... а зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Если используете Retrofit2 то можно через него отправить. Сделаете файл с json. И примерно так будет выглядеть метод отправки

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("description") RequestBody description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}


private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
// create upload service client
FileUploadService service =
        ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

// https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
// use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

// create RequestBody instance from file
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

// add another part within the multipart request
String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
RequestBody description =
        RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```

Вот собственно где подробно все расписано:

[Пример загрузки фала на сервер](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)